# SweetAlert2 allows an ASP.NET Core MVC form to post with missing required data. How to fix this?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, sweetalert2

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with a large form, including many required fields. If the user tries to submit the form with missing required information, I want to include an alert message as part of the feedback, and to keep the design simple I'm trying to incorporate said feedback into the `jquery.validate` process.

After playing around with the `jquery.validate` code, I have determined the place to set off my notifications is at the end of the `onErrors` function in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, found at line 69 in my copy of the library:

```
function onErrors(event, validator) {  // 'this' is the form element
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]"),
        list = container.find("ul");

    if (list && list.length && validator.errorList.length) {
        list.empty();
        container.addClass("validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");

        $.each(validator.errorList, function () {
            $("<li />").html(this.message).appendTo(list);
        });

        // <-- MY CODE GOES HERE 
    }
}
```

If I use a standard alert message here, I get the expected behavior: the message shows, the user acknowledges, and the validator marks the missing required fields. But if I use a SweetAlert2 message, the submit process is allowed to go straight through to the post every time.

Here's an example of how I'm firing my SweetAlert message:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Required Input Missing',
    html: 'One or more required fields have been left blank.',
    icon: 'error',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    allowEscapeKey: false,
    allowEnterKey: false
});
```

It doesn't matter if I fire this message directly within the onErrors function, or within its own function elsewhere. Any suggestions on what's going on?

Comment: You should not be editing core libraries as your project will break after a routine future update.  You should be using Microsoft's Unobtrusive Validation plugin as per the ASP documention.  If you want more customization than this allows, then use the jQuery Validate plugin directly, without Unobtrusive, which will give you access to customize as per every available plugin setting and option as shown in the jQuery Validate plugin's documentation.

Comment: Have you check [add validation to an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0)? How about use  jQuery client side validation detects the error ? It displays an error message  with missing required information.